# Ruby on Rails weird operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, algorithm

Recently when i try out an open source project from github i come across with this weird operator

```
  layout ->(c) { request.format == :mobile ? "application" : "centered_with_header_with_footer" }
```

My question is, what does `layout ->(c) { }` actually parsing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

this is a new lambda syntax introduced in ruby 1.9. This is equivalent to below:

`layout lambda { |c| request.format == :mobile ? ... }`

Answer (score 2):

I know that lambdas are sexy. :) This is how you role with regular methods.

```
layout :my_layout

private 

def my_layout
  request.format == :mobile ? "application" : "centered_with_header_with_footer"
end
```

Also make sure that `request.format` actually returns symbol since you are comparing it to one.

Answer (score 0):

It is a method `layout` taking a lambda literal `->(){}` as an argument.